# expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

Why GCC refuses to compile this code, and how to fix it?

```
template<size_t ch>
class ChannelsData
{
    std::array<int, ch> vals;

public:

    template<size_t i>
    inline int& at()
    {
        static_assert( i < ch );
        return vals[ i ];
    }
};

template<size_t c>
inline void something(ChannelsData<c>& dest)
{
    dest.at<0>() = 0;
}

int main()
{
    ChannelsData<1> cd;
    something( cd );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Indeed, adding `template` fixed it. Thanks. Funfact: VC++ 2017 compiles original version just fine.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know which one is correct here, the formulation might have changed since C++03 (I cannot find this phrase in C++17 standard).

Comment: ```template<size_t c>
inline void something(ChannelsData<c>& dest)
{
    dest.template at<0>() = 0;
}
```

Comment: ^ you need the .template keyword